# Como colocar cada linha de um ficheiro txt para dentro de um vetor?

Tags: c

O ficheiro tem apenas como conteúdo 3 linhas, que têm de estar obrigatoriamente assim:

```
Idade = 15
Nome = Alvaro
Apelido = Costa
```

este ficheiro é apenas aberto para leitura com `fopen` no modo "r".

Então tenho 3 variáveis declaradas no código:

```
int idade;
char nome[10];
char apelido[10];
```

e preciso de ir buscar essa informação ao ficheiro e atribuir a cada uma das variáveis o seu conteúdo-

Eu li na internet que a função `fgets()` poderia ler linha por linha e colocar a informação da linha para um vetor
mas o que consigo é apenas ler a primeira linha do ficheiro que diz respeito à idade
a partir ai já não dá.

Com o `fscanf()` eu tendo colocar tudo para dentro de um vetor primeiro e ai separar a informação desse vetor
mas não consigo com esta função obter todo o conteúdo do ficheiro.

Qual é a forma mais simples de fazer isto?

---

A minha ideia era colocar cada linha para um vetor em separado
e ai buscava com alguma função no primeiro vetor dígitos e convertia a string que continha dígitos para inteiro e atribuía à variável (`int idade`).

Em relação ao vetor 2 que corresponderia ao nome eu ignorava as primeiras posições que diziam respeito "Nome = " e aproveitava a string dessa posição para a frente formando um novo vetor com apenas o nome.
Em relação ao vetor 3 eu faria o mesmo tratamento que no vetor 2, mas o problema é que nem colocar a informação total do ficheiro para dentro de um array consigo.

O ideal penso que seria colocar cada linha do ficheiro para um vetor e a partir dai eu já me safava.

---

Partilho aqui também o meu código:

```
int idade;
char nome[10];
char apelido[10];

void configuracoes(){

    // colocando aqui toda a informação do ficheiro

    char conteudo[100];

    // OU
    // será possivel pegar em cada linha de um ficheiro e colocar os seus caracteres directamente para cada um destes vetores?
    char linha1[10];
    char linha2[10];
    char linha3[10];


    FILE *f = fopen("dados.txt","r");

    // colocar o conteudo do ficheiro para dentro de um vetor

    // testativa de colocar todo o conteudo do ficheiro para dentro de um vetor // FALHADA
    int i;
    for(i=0; i != EOF; i++){
        conteudo[i] = fscanf(f,"%c", conteudo);
    }


    //fgets(conteudo,100,f);


    for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        printf("%c", conteudo[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    fclose(f);

    //printf("CONFIGURACAO APLICADA\n"); 
}

main(){
    configuracoes();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se tens a certeza absoluta do formato do ficheiro e tens a certeza que o formato nunca vai mudar, podes fazer `if (fscanf(f, "Idade =%d Nome =%.9s Apelido =%.9s", &idade, nome, apelido) != 3) /* erro */;`

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma solução utilizando somente `fscanf()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    FILE * pf = NULL;

    int idade = 0;
    char nome[10] = {0};
    char apelido[10] = {0};

    pf = fopen( "ficheiro.txt", "r" );

    if(!pf)
        return 1;

    fscanf( pf, "Idade = %d\n", &idade );
    fscanf( pf, "Nome = %s\n", nome );
    fscanf( pf, "Apelido = %s\n", apelido );

    fclose(pf);

    printf( "Idade: %d\n", idade );
    printf( "Nome: %s\n", nome );
    printf( "Apelido: %s\n", apelido );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Espero que seja util!

Answer (score 0):

Existe varias maneiras de resolver o problema, a mais simples seria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int idade;
    char nome[100];
    char apelido[100];
    char trash[100];

    FILE *f = fopen( "dados.txt", "r" );

    // Sempre importante verificar se nao houve erro na abertura
    if( f == NULL )  // Se houve erro na abertura
    {
        printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Lendo a idade
    fscanf( f, "%s%s%d", trash, trash, &idade );
    printf( "Idade: %d \n", idade );
    // Lendo o nome
    fscanf( f, "%s%s%s", trash, trash, nome );
    printf( "Nome: %s \n", nome );
    // Lendo o apelido
    fscanf( f, "%s%s%s", trash, trash, apelido );
    printf( "Apelido: %s \n", apelido );

    close(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Tu pode ler as informações do arquivo até encontrar um espaço utilizando o fscanf e ir armazenando as variáveis que desejar. Outra alternativa que poderia ser feita é utilizar o fgets e fazer uma procura até o caracter '='. Quando encontrar o caracter tu sabe que as próximas posições são o dado.

Pode pegar o dado utilizando um memcpy, ou strcpy e depois converter a idade para inteiro utilizando atoi();

Algumas considerações:

- Cuidado com os limites dos vetores. Se o nome fosse maior que 10 já daria problema;
- Sempre verificar condições de erros;
- fscanf retorna o tamanho do dado lido, o dado é armazenado no endereço passado por parâmetro, cuidado;